# Padding set to 0 but there still exists padding

Tags: html, css, padding

Hope you can help me. The 'form_input_username' has an unexpected padding on the top.
Here is a link to the problem: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/242xw1e/8 .
Hope you can help me!

```css
#input_username_total,
#input_password_total {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: table;
}
#input_username,
#input_password {
  background: url('../img/blank_input_login.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  display: table-cell;
}
#input_img {
  width: 16%;
  display: table-cell;
}
#pic_username,
#pic_password {
  width: 100%;
}
#form_input_username,
#form_input_password {
  font-size: 5.5vw;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 94%;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_username_total" class="center">
  <div id="input_img">
    <img src="img/username_pic.png" id="pic_username"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="input_username">
    <input type="text" id="form_input_username" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked to see if theres a margin-top ?

Comment: Note its pretty hard to see what's going on from the posted code: http://jsfiddle.net/7zs7a0u9/

Comment: hi, can u post a fiddle sample?? It'd b easier for us to sort out the issue??

Comment: Yup, thank you all so much. Will make a fiddle in 1,5 hours

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/8vy6tfde/. The height should be the height of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `display: table-cell` for setting elements side by side.

If you want to 'center' the text input, see `vertical-align`

```
#input_username, #input_password {vertical-align: middle}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/11z1rbs7/1/

But I think the better solution is to use `float: left;` instead of `display: table-cell`, elements will be aligned another way and I think you will have less problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved a part of the problem, the input is now in the center. Unfortunately the height of the second div (input_username) is still a bit greater due to the padding, which I do not know how to delete

Comment: @Jasper: if you send me a link to working website, I can help you with your 'padding' - it will be st. else, from image I don't know what exactly, but I can look on it.

Comment: Thanks, but it is an monaca app and I don't know how to put it online since I do not have a server

Comment: Will make a fiddle example in 1,5 hours

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/8vy6tfde/. The height should be the height of the image

Comment: @Jasper: `vertical-align: middle` to `#pic_username`, see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8vy6tfde/3/. I added there three lines at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `vertical-align` to the containing div like so:

```css
#input_username_total,
#input_password_total {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: table;
}
#input_username,
#input_password {
  background: url('../img/blank_input_login.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#input_img {
  width: 16%;
  display: table-cell;
}
#pic_username,
#pic_password {
  width: 100%;
}
#form_input_username,
#form_input_password {
  font-size: 5.5vw;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  padding-left: 4%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 94%;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_username_total" class="center">
  <div id="input_img">
    <img src="img/username_pic.png" id="pic_username"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="input_username">
    <input type="text" id="form_input_username" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This then aligns everything to the middle and therefore keep everything in line.

Answer (score 0):

Please click the jsfiddle link, as NoLiver92 pointed out, you had some margin which was effecting it.

http://jsfiddle.net/cze3u1wz/

I just removed the margin, new css is:

```
#input_username_total, #input_password_total {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 width: 80%;
 display: table;
}

#input_username, #input_password {
 background: url('../img/blank_input_login.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 margin-left: -2px;
 display: table-cell;
 }

#input_img {
 width: 16%;
 display: table-cell;
}

#pic_username, #pic_password {
 width: 100%;
}

#form_input_username, #form_input_password {
 font-size: 5.5vw;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 background: transparent;
 padding-left: 4%;
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 94%;
}
```

Comment: This does not align the input and image which is what the user is requesting

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but this unfortunately does not work